# How to actually use a validation set when using support vector machines in sklearn

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation

While working with SVMs, I am seeing that it is a good practice to perform a three way split on the original data set, something along the lines of, say, a 70/15/15 split.

This split would correspond to %70 for training, %15 for testing, and %15 for what is referred to as "validation."

I'm fairly clear on **why** this is a good practice, but I'm not sure about the nuts and bolts needed to actually perform this.  Lots of online sources discuss the importance, but I can't seem to find a definite (or at least algorithmic) description of the process.  For example, sklearn discusses it [here](http://www.astroml.org/sklearn_tutorial/practical.html#cross-validation-and-testing) but stops before giving any solid tools.

Here's my idea:

- Train the algorithm, using *training set*
- Find error rate, using *testing set*
- ??  tweak parameters
- Get error rate again, using *validation set*

If anyone could point me in the direction of a good resource, I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 3):

The role of the validation set in all supervised learning algorithms is to find the optimium for the parameters of the algorithm (if there are any).

After splitting your data into traing/validation/test data, the best practise to train an algorithm is like that:

1. choose initial learning parameters
2. train the algorithm using the training set and the parameters
3. get the (validation) accuracy using the validation set (cross-validation test)
4. change parameters and continue with 2 until found parameters leading to best validation accuracy
5. get the (test) accuracy using the test set which represents the actual expected accuracy of your trained algorithm on new unseen data.

There are some advanced approaches for performing the cross-validation test. Some libraries like libsvm have them included: the **k-fold cross validation**.

In k-fold cross validation you split your train data randomly into k same-sized portions. You train using k-1 portions and cross validate with the remaining portion. You do this k-times with different subsets and finally using the average.

Wikipedia is a good source:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supervised_learning
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_%28statistics%29